# Module requires Composer install of third-party library

Tags: composer, aegir

I am trying to learn about drupal 8 and composer within aegir. It seems like aegir has some support for it but the problem that I am running into right now is that aegir doesn't seem to install composer dependencies for modules. For instance, I am using the "real_aes" module in my first drupal 8 deploy which requires that defuse php-encryption be required. Normally, I would just use composer require and everything would be no problem. However, I am trying to use aegir to manage all of this.

My question is really this. Is there a way in aegir to specify composer requirements or to get aegir to install all module requirements based on the module's composer.json file? And if not, what is the best way to handle this via aegir? Will i need to alter the composer.json file in the drupal root directory after I deploy the drupal 8 platform and run composer update via the command line or are there any other work-arounds that would be better?

I should say that I found the hosting_composer module and installed it and it's dependencies. However, I immediately got several warnings right after install. Since this is going to be managing live drupal sites, I am hesitant to rely on so many dev modules especially since they are showing issues right after install.

I have about 20-30 drupal 7 sites that I am looking to migrate to d8 over the next year.

Comment: [Aegir Composer](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting_composer) was written before Aegir core had any support for Composer so there are conflicts now.  To properly work with core, and add new functionality, the work described in [Enhance composer support in Aegir core](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting_composer/issues/2938992) will need to get done.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing a similar problem, I just wanted to add that, as of Aegir 3.18, it seems possible to configure Composer to download and install third party libraries for Drupal modules from https://asset-packagist.org. Of course, those libraries should exist as Composer packages on the asset-packagist site.

I was able to get this going yesterday by following the instructions at the link below, but after a lot of trial and error as the docs are not always accurate, especially in terms of the line endings, JSON syntax etc.:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#third-party-libraries

The composer.json file to edit is at the Aegir path /platforms/drupal-x.x.x/composer.json